# What order of the cases did the Romans use when declining nouns?

Tags: declension, case, teaching-method

In modern books, two orders of the cases can be found: *nom, gen, dat, acc, abl*, and *nom, acc, gen, dat, abl*. Which one did the Romans use? Or did they use some entirely different order?